# Modify wordpress template - adding submenu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, submenu

I'm doing some maintenance on a website. I thought it was easy but I can't display submenu. The costumer said that the template was developed for them so probably the submenu feature was not included in it.

I don't know much php (actually I know very few) and I can't find a solution on google. I can use html and css pretty well to style it but before I need it to display.

here is the code I have in the header.php:

```
<span id="toggle_nav" class="icon-menu"></span>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-navigation', 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'depth' => 1, 'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Daniele

Comment: Try to change 'depth' => 1 to 'depth' => 0 and check it.

Comment: thanks, it worked... even if it messed up all the menu in terms of css... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Ash Patel was indeed the right solution:

```
'depth' => 1
```

to

```
'depth' => 0
```